# deepcopy() is highly inefficient in copying a large graph object

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, python-3.8, deep-copy

Code is in Python.
There is a graph object, which in turn consists of vertex objects and edge objects.
I have to copy the complete graph object into a new graph object.

Using `deepcopy` is proving to be highly inefficient, not sure why.
It takes 170 secs out of total runtime of 200 secs just to copy using `deepcopy`.

One execution of `deepcopy` takes around 1 sec. Since, there is a loop, so all executions of `deepcopy` account for 170 secs out of total 200 secs

Sharing the code below:

```
import copy

class Vertex: 

    def __init__(self, key):

        self.key = key
        self.label = None
        self.neighbors = set()
        self.incident_edges = set()  
        self.in_left = None

    def get_edge(self, neighbor):
        
        for e in self.incident_edges:
            if neighbor in e.vertices:
                return e

        return False

    def set_label(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def set_in_left(self, in_left):
        self.in_left = in_left

    def filter_neighbors(self):  
        new_neighbors = set()

        for v in self.neighbors:            
            for e in self.incident_edges:   
                if v == e.vertices[0] or v == e.vertices[1]:
                    new_neighbors.add(v)
                    break

        self.neighbors = new_neighbors



class Edge:

    def __init__(self, v1, v2, weight = math.inf, heur = False):
        '''Edge constructor.

        Parameters
        ----------
        v1 : str, required (endpoint1 key)
        v2 : str, required (endpoint2 key)
        weight : int, optional (default = inf)
        '''
        self.vertices = [v1, v2]
        self.weight = weight
        
        if heur == True:
            self.typeOfWeight = 'h'  # can be 'h' - for heuristic or 'a' - for actual weight
        else:
            self.typeOfWeight = None 


    
    def get_pair_vertex(self, v):
        for vertex in self.vertices:
            if ( vertex != v.key ):
                return vertex


    
    def __eq__(self, e):
        '''Edges with equal endpoints and weights are equal.'''
        return (self.vertices == e.vertices
                and self.weight == e.weight)

    def __hash__(self):
        '''Hash the vertices (frozen set) and weight.'''
        return hash((frozenset(self.vertices), self.weight))


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


class Graph:

    def __init__( self, G = {}, heur = False ):
        
        self.vertices = {}
        
        # If the input graph is in the form of an adjacency matrix (then we won't have vertex labels such as 'r1', 't1' in the input; rather we need to create them)

        goals_lessThan_robots = False  # change 999

        if type(G) is not dict:
            
            # change 999 - for handling case when no of robots != no of goals

            if G.shape[1] < G.shape[0]:  # that is, if the no of goals is < nof of robots, then we change the left-right orientation
                goals_lessThan_robots = True
            
            for i in range(G.shape[0]):
                v1 = 'r' + str(i)
                for j in range(G.shape[1]):
                    v2 = 'g' + str(j)
                    # self.add_edge(v1, v2, G[i][j])  change 999
                    self.add_edge(v1, v2, G[i][j], goals_lessThan_robots, heur)  # change 999

        else:  # if the input graph is in the form of dictionary

            for v1 in G:
                for v2 in G[v1]:
                    # self.add_edge(v1, v2, G[v1][v2])  # change 999
                    self.add_edge(v1, v2, G[v1][v2], goals_lessThan_robots, heur) 
                    
    def add_vertex(self, key):
        '''
        Adds a vertex to the graph.
        '''
        self.vertices[key] = Vertex(key)  # aks - instantiates a Vertex object and adds in Graphs' vertex dictionary


    def add_edge( self, v1, v2, weight = math.inf, goals_lessThan_robots = False, heur = False ):
        '''
        Adds an edge to the graph.
        '''

        if v1 not in self.vertices:
            self.add_vertex(v1)
        if v2 not in self.vertices:
            self.add_vertex(v2)

        
        e = Edge(v1, v2, weight, heur)

        self.vertices[v1].neighbors.add(v2)
        self.vertices[v2].neighbors.add(v1)
        self.vertices[v1].incident_edges.add(e)
        self.vertices[v2].incident_edges.add(e)
        
            self.vertices[v1].set_in_left(True)    # aks 98
            self.vertices[v2].set_in_left(False)   # aks 98

def edge_in_equality_subgraph(self, e):
        '''
        Determines whether edge is in equality subgraph
        '''
        
        e_endpoints = list(e.vertices)

        if (self.vertices[e_endpoints[0]].label == None or 
            self.vertices[e_endpoints[1]].label == None):
            return False

        return e.weight == (self.vertices[e_endpoints[0]].label + 
                            self.vertices[e_endpoints[1]].label)

    def equality_subgraph(self):
        '''
        Creates an equality subgraph with respect to labeling
        '''

        eq_H = copy.deepcopy(self)

        for v in eq_H.vertices:             
            
            eq_H.vertices[v].incident_edges = list(filter(
                self.edge_in_equality_subgraph, 
                eq_H.vertices[v].incident_edges))
            
            eq_H.vertices[v].filter_neighbors()

        return eq_H
```

In another method, I have below calls:

```
G = Graph( _G, heur = True )
eq_G = G.equality_subgraph()
```

The first line in `equality_subgraph` function is using `deepcopy` and is the culprit.
I created a bipartite graph, with 100 vertices on left and 100 vertices on right, so 200 vertices in total.

Request for help.

Comment: Yes, `copy.deepcopy` is not very efficient, it needs to be able to handle arbitrary objects. You should just write a copying logic yourself for this if you need better performance

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga By "write a copying logic youself", do you mean I should create new objects (vertices, edges and lastly the graph object) just like original graph object ?

Comment: Yes? Whatever you feel is necessary

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, will try and update. Thanks.